# Return address buffer from one file to another

Tags: c, return, return-value, function-calls

I have two files: `mainfile.c` and `kmeans.c`. I want to return the addresses of the buffers that are allocated in `kmeans.c` back to  `mainfile.c`. The following is the process:

**kmeans.c**

```
void kmeans(int *cluster_assign, int *cluster_size,){
    cluster_assign = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
    cluster_size = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    // Some operations on both buffers

    return cluster_assign, cluster_size     //  <<<< Here I want to return the address of both buffers to main
}
```

**mainfile.c**

```
int main(){

    int *cluster_size = NULL;
    int *cluster_assign = NULL;

    kmeans(cluster_centers, cluster_size);

    // Here, I don't know how to acquire the addresses that were allocated in kmeans(...)

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, if I don't return the addresses from `kmeans.c`, I cannot proceed in `mainfile.c`. I tried many ways including arrays of pointers but it was wrong. Any help is apprciated.

Comment: Use `void kmeans(int *&cluster_assign, int *&cluster_size,){` instead, you can't return more than one value, especially not with a `void` return type.

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag as `cluster_assign = malloc(...)` doesn't compile as C++.

Comment: C isn't Python. In C a function can just return exactly *one* value.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: C isn't C++. her are no references in C.

Comment: @alk You may have overlooked that the question was originally tagged c++

Answer (score 0):

A statement like

```
   return cluster_assign, cluster_size;
```

is the same as

```
   return cluster_size;
```

as, here, the [comma-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is in effect. The LHS of comma operator will be evaluated and discarded, the RHS operand will be the actual in-effect return value.

Basically, you cannot have a `return` statement returning values of two variable with a single statement from a function.

- You can however, always form a structure (`struct` variable) with the members as two elements and return that.
- As an alternative, you can take a pointer to the variable you want to be modified inside the function, do the operation and happily return `void` (nothing, `return ;` or simply omit the return statement.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using double pointers

```
void kmeans(int **cluster_assign, int **cluster_size,){
    *cluster_assign = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
    *cluster_size = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    // Some operations on both buffers
}


int main(){

    int *cluster_size = NULL;
    int *cluster_assign = NULL;

    kmeans(&cluster_centers, &cluster_size);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much